# How to reduce image size while taking from gallery through imagepath

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, bitmapimage, bitmapfactory

I want to take image from camera and also take from gallery that part i did .
when i take images from one activity to other through image path it show memory out error on taking fourth image ,so i want to take image from  gallery and when i take image from gallery it should be compressed so it should not have out of memory error byte allocation.

thanks.

Here is my code can anybody help in this

```
imageview1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    imageview2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    imageview3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
    imageview4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4);


    Bitmap b = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data") ;

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    locationname = preferences.getString("Location", "Location");

    SharedPreferences preferences1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    categoryname = preferences1.getString("categoryname", "categoryname");

    SharedPreferences imagepath1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath1 = imagepath1.getString("picturePath1", "picturePath1");


    SharedPreferences imagepath2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath2 = imagepath2.getString("picturePath2", "picturePath2");

    SharedPreferences imagepath3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath3 = imagepath3.getString("picturePath3", "picturePath3");

    SharedPreferences imagepath4 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath4 = imagepath4.getString("picturePath4", "picturePath4");


    Bitmap thumbnail1 = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath1));
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);

    Bitmap thumbnail2 = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath2));
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream1);

    Bitmap thumbnail3 = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath3));
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream2);

    Bitmap thumbnail4 = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath4));
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail4.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream3);


    imageview1.setImageBitmap(thumbnail1);
    thumbnail1.recycle();
    imageview2.setImageBitmap(thumbnail2);
    imageview3.setImageBitmap(thumbnail3 );
    imageview4.setImageBitmap(thumbnail4);
```

Answer (score 2):

it happens because of image size. you have to resize or compress images. below code will help you for that. use as per your needed:

```
public static Bitmap loadResizedBitmap( String filename, int width, int height, boolean exact ) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filename, options );
    if ( options.outHeight > 0 && options.outWidth > 0 ) {
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        while (    options.outWidth  / options.inSampleSize > width
                && options.outHeight / options.inSampleSize > height ) {
            options.inSampleSize++;
        }
        options.inSampleSize--;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filename, options );
        if ( bitmap != null && exact ) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmap, width, height, false );
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

OR

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code:-**

```
 public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {               imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);               actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;             } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filename;

    }
```

http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

in android, each bitmap that is loaded to memory, get "width*height*4 bytes" of memory size.
so you should bring an smaller bitmap to memory.
look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)